# Aggregate functions in having

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, aggregate-functions, having

I understand why aggregate functions have to be used in the having part of a query, by do not understand the reasoning why the two queries bellow return different values ie. what each of the functions is returning:

```
SELECT col1 FROM tbl
HAVING col1 > AVG(col1);

SELECT col1 FROM tbl
HAVING col1 > SELECT(AVG(col1) FROM tbl);
```

Answer (score 1):

This query has an aggregation function:

```
SELECT col1
FROM tbl
HAVING col1 > AVG(col1);
```

Hence, it is an aggregation query with no `group by` and it returns one row.  The question is:  what is the value of `col1` in the `HAVING` clause.

Well, MySQL has extended SQL to allow this syntax.  It takes an *arbitrary* value of `col1` from an indeterminate row.  So, it arbitrarily compares some value of `col1` to the average.  That is probably not what you want.  Note:  This syntax would fail in almost any other database.

The second query:

```
SELECT col1
FROM tbl
HAVING col1 > SELECT(AVG(col1) FROM tbl);
```

has not aggregation for the outer reference to `tbl`.  So, it is using a different MySQL extension.  In this case, the `HAVING` is equivalent to `WHERE`:

```
SELECT col1
FROM tbl
WHERE col1 > (SELECT AVG(col1) FROM tbl);
```

(Note that the parentheses are fixed.)

And this does what you want.  The `WHERE` version is probably what you intend and will work in any database.

Answer (score 0):

here in the 1st query though in mysql syntactically does not throw error but logically it is meaning less . note:This query will be thrown error in sql server though syntax right

```
  SELECT col1 FROM tbl
    HAVING col1 > AVG(col1);
```

2nd query generate complete avg values of col1 for whole table in sub-query and compare this value with col1

```
    SELECT col1 FROM tbl
    HAVING col1 > SELECT(AVG(col1) FROM tbl);
```

Thats why you got the two different types of output